# Haskell: List Comprehensions

Tags: list, haskell, list-comprehension

I am practicing for my exam and have problems solving the following list-comprehensions-exercises:

a) Create the infinite list of square numbers n^2, with n element of N,
which are even numbers, have the rest 2 when they are divided by 9 and have the rest 3 when divided by 35, which means:

```
    [1444,446224,1684804,3717184,...]
```

b) Create a list of tupel (a, b, c, d) for all a ∈ {10, 34, 77, 180}, b ∈ {’p’,’r’,’g’}, c ∈ {False, True} and d ∈ {’Y’,’Z’}. The order of the elements should change numbers first, then lower letters, then boolean value and then upper letters, which means:

```
    [(10,’p’,False,’Y’),(34,’p’,False,’Y’),(77,’p’,False,’Y’) 
    (180,’p’,False,’Y’),(10,’r’,False,’Y’),(34,’r’,False,’Y’), 
    (77,’r’,False,’Y’),(180,’r’,False,’Y’)...]
```

I am not quite sure how to implement this in actual haskell code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a)

```
[n^2 | n <- [2, 4..],
       n `mod` 9 == 2,
       n `mod` 35 == 3]
```

For b) it's important to list the sets in reverse order.

```
[(a, b, c, d) | d <- ['Y', 'Z'],
                c <- [True, False],
                b <- ['p', 'r', 'g'],
                a <- [10, 34, 77, 180]]
```

Comment: The comprehension for A can be sped up a bit by using `[3, 38..]` as the source instead of the even numbers. That way it skips more invalid numbers.